# Masonry & Infinite Ajax Scroll

Tags: javascript, dle

Добрый день!
Прошу помощи! Вопрос в следующем. Используется Masonry & Infinite Ajax Scroll. Всё работает стабильно, за исключением одного. На странице выводится по два блока (слева и справа). При прокрутке страницы подгружаются ниже также следующие по два блока. Но получается так, что блоки загружаются, накладываясь на первые два, а потом сразу же становятся/выстраиваются ниже, как и должно быть. Прокручиваем страницу: также следующие два блока загружаются, сначала накладываясь на первые два, и тут же сразу после этого перестраиваются вниз. И так со всеми остальными блоками.
Прошу прощения за каламбур, попыталась объяснить подробно.
Скрипты подключаю следующим образом:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{THEME}/js/jquery.ias.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{THEME}/js/masonry.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var container = document.querySelector('#container');
        var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
          // options
          columnWidth: 482,
          isResizable: true,
          isFitWidth: true,
          itemSelector: '.block-shortstory',
          gutter: 0
        });

        var ias = $.ias({
          container: "#container",
          item: ".block-shortstory",
          pagination: "#page_navigation",
          next: ".page_navigation a",
          delay: 1200
        });

        ias.on('render', function(items) {
          $(items).css({ opacity: 1 });
        });

        ias.on('rendered', function(items) {
          msnry.appended(items);
        });

        ias.extension(new IASSpinnerExtension());
        ias.extension(new IASNoneLeftExtension({html: '<div class="ias-noneleft" style="text-align:center"><p><em>Всё!</em></p></div>'}));
</script>
```

Comment: Прошу закрыть вопрос, решен. Нужно было opacity: поставить 0.

Comment: Вы можете самостоятельно удалить вопрос

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен. Нужно было opacity: поставить 0

```
$(items).css({ opacity: 0 });
```

Comment: Так он там в одном лишь месте, ошибиться просто нельзя)